# Mathematica translate - getting multiple copies

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The command is

```
Show[{PolyhedronData["TruncatedOctahedron"], 
  Graphics3D[
   Translate[
    PolyhedronData["TruncatedOctahedron", "Faces"], {30, 30, 30}],
   {40, 40, 40}
     ]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which creates 1 additional copy of the original figure. If I want 1 more copy of it on the same image, how do I specify the translation vector for it? How should this command be modified?

Answer (score 5):

In versions 6 and 7 you pretty much have to create a table of translated figures:

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[Translate[PolyhedronData["TruncatedOctahedron", "Faces"], 
   10 {Cos[2 i], Sin[i], Cos[3 i]}], {i, 60}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In version 8 you can also use one figure with a table of translation vectors:

```
Graphics3D[
 Translate[PolyhedronData["TruncatedOctahedron", "Faces"], 
  Table[10 {Cos[2 i], Sin[i], Cos[3 i]}, {i, 60}]]]
```

which can save memory and be a bit quicker.